# PHP Word, send generated file to browser as output without saving it on disc

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PHP Word & htmltodocx_converter to create a word document, all works well but I just need an example of how I can send the file to browser for download without saving it on disc. All examples I see you save the file to your disc:

```
// Save File
$h2d_file_uri = tempnam( "", "htd" );
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter( $phpword_object, "Word2007" );
$objWriter->save( $filename ); // At this line, I would like to output the file to the browser
```

Anyone knows of how I can output the file to the browser on the fly?

Comment: possibly you can pass in `php://output` as `$filename`, if not just create a normal file, create the correct headers, read it to output with `readfile` then delete it with `unlink`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This below example maybe works, but to get the expected behaviour of the download in all browsers, the `Content-Type` header has to be correct for Word2007. Maybe you will need some additional headers for proper output.

You can try this:

```
$filename = "YOUR_Filename.docx";
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing‌​ml.document" );// you should look for the real header that you need if it's not Word 2007!!!
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename );

$h2d_file_uri = tempnam( "", "htd" );
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter( $phpword_object, "Word2007" );
$objWriter->save( "php://output" );// this would output it like echo, but in combination with header: it will be sent
```

Thanks to @jamsandwich: The correct header for Word 2007 should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing‌​ml.document`.

[Reference Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)

Comment: The content type for Word 2007 is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` [(reference)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)

Comment: Note the file extension should also be .docx for a Word 2007+ document, rather than .doc