# show doc,docx file content php

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpword

I have problem that showing the content or `docx` file in `php(laravel 5)`.
I did not find any solution to show the content. I use `phpword` lib for reading, I read the document of phpword but not find the solution.
Here is my code:
+upload in html:

```
<form method="post" action="doc/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="file" name="file" accept=".doc, .docx"/>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import" aria-hidden="true"></span> Upload</button>
        </form>
```

+ process:

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file);
    //i use this line below for showing but it can not show exactly 
    $phpWord->save('php://output');
}
```

+result:
[image]

Comment: you are missing the header informations, i.e. the browser doesn't get enough information on how handle the output. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872714/php-word-send-generated-file-to-browser-as-output-without-saving-it-on-disc for similar question.

Comment: You can refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72698699/5783617

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for the answer for this and here's my code to read a docx file using PHPWord. I'm completing the steps from installation (this is for laravel 5)

Step 1. add https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord in your composer file. (composer.json)

```
"require": {
       "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
    }
```

Step 2. Add to your controller the IOFactory.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
```

Step 3. create a reader and load the file.

```
$phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($request->file('file')->path());
```

Step 4. You can already check the $phpWord for properties and contents of the document.

Step 5. If you want to extract the contents of document. use code below

```
$phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($request->file('file')->path());

foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
            foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
                if(method_exists($element,'getText')) {
                    echo($element->getText() . "<br>");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, to my shame I wasn't able to find any advanced documentation regarding reading Word documents, do you have a link by any chance?

Comment: @SergeyNeskhodovskiy , sorry don't have any documentation, i just found the solution online and trial and error.

Comment: Documentation is here i think : https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show all word doc contetns, then the best way would be to save the word file as html and then show html contents in an Iframe.

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('doc.html');
```

if you want to grab just the plain text contents from the doc, you might try something like this

```
foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
    foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
        if(method_exists($element,'getText')) {
            echo($element->getText() . "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a simpler (and in my case, much more accurate) way of converting a Microsoft Word document to plain text, I would recommend taking a look at this thread found here: [How to extract text from word file .doc,docx,.xlsx,.pptx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Rabb-bit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5297877/rabb-bit) answer, The loop was not working for me so this may help. We just need to load the file and then can get the content without formatting from a doc/Docx file.

```
$phpWord = IOFactory::load( $filePath );

foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
        foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
            if (method_exists($element, 'getElements')) {
                foreach($element->getElements() as $childElement) {
                    if (method_exists($childElement, 'getText')) {
                        $content .= $childElement->getText() . ' ';
                    }
                    else if (method_exists($childElement, 'getContent')) {
                        $content .= $childElement->getContent() . ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (method_exists($element, 'getText')) {
                $content .= $element->getText() . ' ';
            }
        }
    }
```