# mkdir(): No such file or directory Error In PhpWord and Laravel 10

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos7, phpword

Am trying to save a word document using PhpWord 1.0 object Writer within the storage folder in laravel 10 but am getting an exception "**mkdir(): No such file or directory"**. The logic is as follows:

```
 // Set MS Word compatibility to MS Office 2007
        $phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(12);

        $filesBasePath = storage_path('app/references/');

        $referenceDir = session()->get('random_files_dir');

        if (!empty($referenceDir) and is_dir($filesBasePath . $referenceDir)) {

            $absoluteRefPath = $filesBasePath . $referenSceDir;
            // Saving the document as OOXML file.
            $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
            $objWriter->save($absoluteRefpath . '/references.docx');
        } else {
            $referenceDir = Str::random(8);
            $absoluteRefPath = $filesBasePath . $referenceDir;

            if (!File::isDirectory($absoluteRefPath)) {
                if (File::makeDirectory($absoluteRefPath, 0755, true, true)) {
                    // Saving the document as OOXML file.
                    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
                    $objWriter->save($absoluteRefPath . '/references.docx');

                    session(['random_files_dir' => $referenceDir]);
                }
            }
        }

        return response()->download($absoluteRefPath . '/references.docx')
```

What might be the issue? Am running on centos 7

I was expecting the word document to be save inside storage/app/references/random folder. The random folder is being created but the the Phpword Object writer throws an exception. the below Line is the one that throws an error;

```
$objWriter->save(storage_path('references.docx'));
```

Comment: Does `storage/references.docx ` exist?

Comment: Yes it already exists and also the random folder is also being created.

Comment: The code is running on my local machine but when i upload it on hosting server which is also centos 7, an exception is thrown

Comment: check permissions for folders on the remote serever

Comment: The permissions are as follows:
storage folder:                     drwxrwsr-x  ;
storage/app                         drwxrwsr-x   ;
storage/app/references:       drwxr-sr-x  ;

Comment: The references  permissions are owner: read/write/execute, group: read/execute-setuid, everyone: read/execute. Make sure all of the directories are owned by the webserver user (apache, www-data)

Comment: _"What might be the issue? Am running on centos 7"_ - Perhaps SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the issue by setting the value for temp directory in php.ini file as follows:

```
sys_temp_dir = "/temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having difficulties with the file system. First consider making the processing simpler. This should not solve your problem, as mkdir() is still called on this path under the cover, but who knows:

```php
// Set MS Word compatibility to MS Office 2007
$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(12);

$filesBasePath = storage_path('app/references/');

$referenceDir = session()->get('random_files_dir');
if (empty($referenceDir)) {
    $referenceDir = Str::random(8);
    session(['random_files_dir' => $referenceDir]);
}

$absoluteRefPath = $filesBasePath . $referenceDir;
File::ensureDirectoryExists($absoluteRefPath, 0755, true, true);

// Saving the document as OOXML file.
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($absoluteRefPath . '/references.docx');

return response()->download($absoluteRefPath . '/references.docx')
```

Now, if I don't mistake your code, the part that is causing the issue is only to create the temporary directory for the file to save temporarily for the download.

If so, this is not necessary at all. It's perhaps a bit cheap as that is what you're worried about in your question, but if you could just output the docx file without the round-trip on the file-system first:

```php
// Set MS Word compatibility to MS Office 2007
$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(12);
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($objWriter) {    
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}, 'references.docx')
```

This reduces the code down to five lines and has no mkdir() call any longer, also session is not needed. YMMV.

- *[PHP Word, send generated file to browser as output without saving it on disc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33872714/367456)*
- *[Laravel HTTP Responses: Streamed Downloads](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#streamed-downloads)*

Comment: The bug still persist. I Have tried all the above but the error still can be resolved

Comment: I guess you mean can't. So even with the second alternative, the code that does not save a file nor creates a directory, you still get the mkdir() error, right? Which line of it does it cause?

Comment: This line is the one that through error: $objWriter->save($absoluteRefPath . '/references.docx');

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php:203

Comment: Can Selinux be the cause of the error?

Comment: _"Can Selinux be the cause of the error?"_ I can't say, this is something the administrator of that system could say. My earlier comment was merely a hint. The error btw. is not from your code (unless you call setTempDir() somewhere which I doubt). The error is from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php#L203 . From it's code, the code-path could be triggered by using php://output (compare with the docblock comment of protected function getTempFile()). Check for PHP warnings, log them. They could reveal the directories this actually is about.